# Check if selenium instagram post is a video

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I have a bot that loops over all user posts and get the number of likes and it's link. The problem is that the code breaks when it encounters a video.

```
def usermostlikedposts(self, username, nofposts):
        self.nav_user(username)
        for i in range(nofposts):
            try:
                post = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class=\'eLAPa\']//parent::a)[{}]'.format(i+1))
                post.click()
                WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH , '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[2]/div/div/button/span')))
                likes = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[2]/div/div/button/span').get_attribute("innerHTML")
                link = post.get_attribute("href")
                self.likesposts[likes] = link
                x = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/button')
                x.click()
            except:
                pass
```

.

I don't know how to make this work on videos, i want to make the bot get the number of views instead of likes whenever it encounters a video, but i fail to implement this. I'm looking for a way to check if the post is a video, and write the code according to that condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it:

```
def usermostlikedposts(self, username, nofposts):
        self.nav_user(username)
        for i in range(nofposts):
            try:
                post = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class=\'eLAPa\']//parent::a)[{}]'.format(i+1))
                post.click()
                WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH , '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[3]/button')))
                try:
                    likes = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[2]/div/div/button/span').get_attribute("innerHTML")
                    link = post.get_attribute("href")
                    self.likesposts[likes] = link
                except:
                    pass
                x = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/button')
                x.click()
            except:
                pass
```